# Accessing push payload if app is inactive

Tags: ios, push, appdelegate

I have a push notification, and when app receives it, I call the following

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    if userInfo["t"] as! String == "rqst"  {

        print("type is help request")

        if let token = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("authToken") {
            authTokenOfHelper = token as! String
        }

        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("helperMap")
        let navController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: viewController)
        self.window?.rootViewController = nil
        self.window?.rootViewController = navController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        helpRequestReceived = true

    }

}
```

this initialises storyboard.But if my app was killed by system and it is off and device recieves push, after tapping on push nothing is happened.

Seems that I have to use  `application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?)` if app is switched off

But how to access userInfo in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this in didFinishLaunching using `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey` as launch options.

> UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey: Indicates that a
>   remote notification is available for the app to process. The value of
>   this key is an NSDictionary containing the payload of the remote
>   notification. > - alert: Either a string for the alert message or a
>   dictionary with two keys: body and show-view. > - badge: A number
>   indicating the quantity of data items to download from the provider.
>   This number is to be displayed on the app icon. The absence of a badge
>   property indicates that any number currently badging the icon should
>   be removed. > - sound: The name of a sound file in the app bundle to
>   play as an alert sound. If “default” is specified, the default sound
>   should be played.

You can  call `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` manually.

**Objective C**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // ...

    if (launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]) {
        [self application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]];
    }

   return YES;
}
```

**Swift**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        if let remoteNotification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? NSDictionary {

            self.application(application, didReceiveRemoteNotification: launchOptions![UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]! as! [NSObject : AnyObject])

        }


        return true
    }
```

Comment: tried code, but nothing happens if I open the push. The app doesnt open

Comment: Application is not open or didReceiveRemoteNotification not called ?

Comment: oh no, sorry, app opens, but then crashes immediately

Comment: Answer updated for swift code. Please check now. Thanks

Comment: @technerd, Objective-c code is missing return value.

Answer (score 0):

This is in Objective C but the same thing is in Swift. Put this in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
NSDictionary *remoteNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
if (remoteNotif) {
    [self application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:remoteNotif];
}
```

Swift:

```
if let remoteNotif = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? NSDictionary {...}
```

Comment: Inside `didReceiveRemoteNotification:remoteNotif` i use `    [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:@{}];` but it doesn't work.